# How to iteratively plot lines with colors from a sequential color function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, colormap

I would like to plot 3 figures in python. I plotted it manually. 
The code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)    
Semesters=np.arange(1,7,1)
y1=np.arange(10,16,1)
y2=np.arange(20,26,1)
y3=np.arange(51,57,1)
plt.plot(Semesters, y1,label="To Reach 120",linewidth=2)
plt.plot(Semesters, y2,label="To Reach 100",linewidth=2)
plt.plot(Semesters, y3,label="To Reach 80",linewidth=2)
ax.set_xticks(Semesters)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, .3), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image]

I want to use for loop and rainbow function (or any other sequential color function) for its color considering legends. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution for you.

**Explanation**: Create your y-data in a list (`y_list` here) and store your labels (`labels` here). Then just loop over the lists to plot one at a time using a `for` loop as you asked.

To define the colors using a color map, `rainbow` for instance, create a list of colors using the number of lines (plots) you have (3 in the example below). Then just assign those colors within the `for` loop and you have your desired plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    
from matplotlib import cm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)    
Semesters=np.arange(1,7,1)
y_list = [np.arange(10,16,1), np.arange(20,26,1), np.arange(51,57,1)]
labels = ["To Reach 120", "To Reach 100", "To Reach 80"]

# Define the colors to be used using rainbow map (or any other sequential map)
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(y_list)))

# Plot the lines using a for loop
for i in range(len(y_list)):
    plt.plot(Semesters, y_list[i], label=labels[i], linewidth=2., color=colors[i])

ax.set_xticks(Semesters)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, .3), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image]