# Plotting line plots in for loop: try to create a color transition but color remains the same for all lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, line-plot

I'm trying to create a line plot using Matplotlib with a color transition. `df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean` is a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` of shape `(288, 1)`. The x values represent years, the y values percentages for each year. Each line represents a differnt country. I'm trying generate a color transition in the code below but it prints all lines in one color: blue. Yet if I print the numerical values for `color` they all fiffer as intended.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(30, 10))
i = 0
for country in (df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean.index.levels[0]):
    red = i / (len(df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean) - 1)
    green = 0
    blue = 1 - (i / (len(df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean) - 1))
    color = (red, green, blue)
    ax[0].plot(list((df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean.loc[country]).index), list(df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean.loc[country, 'percentage']), label=country, color=color, lw=2)
    i += 1
# rest of code is only labeling axis etc
```

The code above produces[image]

yet I'd like the colors to be something like this:

[image]

Do you guys have any idea what went wrong? I'd really appreciate any hint!

Comment: Can you add a figure showing what this produces, and explain what you want?  Or better yet, provide a full MWE that can be run to see what happens?  If you don't specify the color - will it give the lines different colours as you want?  If so - maybe use mycolours = ['red','black','blue']
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=mycolours) to set the default colours to be those 3

Comment: I tried to edit the post accordingly. For one test case I included an `if` statement: `if`country == 'UK': color = 'r'` and the UK line was colored red while the rest remained blue so that worked.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53087362/2613271 without being able to try your code I can't test it sorry.  Maybe create a sequential colour map `colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean.index.levels[0])))` and then call `color=colors[i]` You'll need `from matplotlib import cm` as well

Comment: fair point, I'll try to add the data (unfortunately it's from a csv file ). I tried the colormap yet the problem remains the same: the color is for all lines the same. Yet if I set the `color` parameter in `plot` to `red` or `g` it changes as expected. I'm lost here.

Comment: You are dividing by `len(df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean)` which probably is very large.  Instead, you'd want to use something like `all_countries = df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean.index.levels[0]`.unique()`, then loop with `for i, country in enumerate(all_countries):` and divide by `len(all_countries)`.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you much, this actually was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be what you're looking for, but the following code creates an iterator to run through colours from a defined gradient, in this case I used 'cool', but you can see more at https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html
linspace breaks this gradient up based on the number of lines you have.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np


num_of_lines = len(df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean.index.levels[0])
color=iter(cm.cool(np.linspace(0,1,num_of_lines)))

for country in (df_MBPS_GT100_groupy_land_jahr_mean.index.levels[0]):
    c=next(color) #Change colour for each line in plot
    
    #Do whatever else you need here

    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', c=c, label=key) #Plot all data for each week
```